Issue with MUI 6.1.5 <Dialog> Styling not applying
Good day to all,
I seem to be having an issue with the styling of Dialog props from mui v6.1.5. I am trying to add some styling to the padding and margins, width to different Dialog Components but it seems none of the styling is getting applied.
<Dialog
  open={dialogOpen}
  onClose={() => {
  setDialogOpen(false)
  handleCustomerSelection(null, true)
  }}
  maxWidth={false}
  PaperProps={{
  sx: {
  width: '550px',
  maxWidth: '90vw',
  m: 'auto',
  padding: '0 5px',
   },
  }}
>

none of these PaperProps get applied
also
<DialogActions style={{ justifyContent: 'center', padding: '20px' }}>

none of these get applied either
i have tried with:
sx={{
 '& .MuiDialog-paper': {
  width: '550px !important',
  maxWidth: '90vw !important',
  margin: 'auto !important',
  padding: '0 5px !important',
  }
}}

const StyledDialog = styled(MuiDialog)`
& .MuiDialog-paper {
  width: 550px;
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 5px;
 }
`;

Thank you for the assistence

That's weird, PaperProps should work. Can you edit your question with more of your code? Also, you can use sx instead of style on your DialogActions, that should work
